# Using Laravel query builder having function throws error "Non grouping field" but the same query works fine in Workbench

Tags: database, laravel-5, eloquent

This is the query which I am trying to get from database in Laravel, but it throws error `Non-grouping field subject`, but it works fine in Workbench and returns the result.

```
$qry = "SELECT t5.Id AS id,t5.UID as testUID,(
    SELECT IF(COUNT(t1.Id) > 0,'yes','no') FROM test_usertest t1 WHERE t1.UserId = {$_userId} AND t1.TestId = t5.Id
        ) as isParticipated,(
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t2.Subject) FROM test_subject t2 WHERE t2.Id IN 
                (SELECT t1.SubjectId FROM test_testsubject t1 WHERE t1.TestId = t5.Id AND t1.Status = 1) 
        ) as subject,t5.Title AS title,t5.startTime,t5.totalMarks,t5.maxEntry,t5.duration,t5.description,t5.registrationCoin,
            t5.status,t5.isNegativeMarks,t5.timeStamp,t5.updateTimeStamp FROM test_test t5 HAVING subject LIKE 
            '%{$_request['subject']}%'";
$data = DB::SELECT($qry);
```

Comment: In Workbench, you probably use specific values, not variable. In a Laravel query, try to use parameter bindings like this `$users = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);` or this `$results = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);`. More info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries).

Comment: what i am trying to say that same code works fine on localhost but on production it throws errror so i am not able to find where i am doing wrong maybe the mysql version prblm or may be the modes allowed in mysql

Comment: You did not say a word about `localhost` or `production`. Workbench does not automatically mean `localhost`, as it can connect to both local and remote (production, staging, whatever you want) databases. Always try be as much precise as possible. It helps a lot. To better understand how to write a good question and get relevant answers, please read [Welcome Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) articles.